# Criar arquivo zip de uma pasta

Tags: php

Galera tenho uma pasta chamada Fotos, como faço para criar um arquivo fotos.zip com todas as fotos la dentro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com a resposta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914750/how-to-zip-a-whole-folder-using-php)

```
$zipFile = "./testZip.zip";
$zipArchive = new ZipArchive();

if (!$zipArchive->open($zipFile, ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE))
    die("Failed to create archive\n");

$zipArchive->addGlob("./*.txt");
if (!$zipArchive->status == ZIPARCHIVE::ER_OK)
    echo "falha ao criar o zip\n";

$zipArchive->close();
```

No exemplo acima, todos os arquivos `.txt` do diretório específico serão adicionados no zip.